# How to get the DOM elements with a colon in the tag

Tags: jquery, dom

I have an element like

```
<namespace:my_name>Some <b>html</b> here!</namespace:my_name>
```

How do I get the jQuery element? This doesnt work:

```
var el = $('namespace:my_name');
alert(el.length) // = 0
```

Comment: Is giving the element 'ID' is possible?

Comment: Thanks @BradChristie. Question can be locked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape the colon, it has a special meaning in CSS selectors

```
 $('namespace\\:my_name');
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape `:`, so try this

```
 $("namespace\\:my_name")
```

From reference

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \.

Visit [Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [jQuery documentation for selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). You must escape the selector with two backslashes like so:

```
$('namespace\\:my_name');
```

This is what is known as a literal. There are several other characters that can also be literals, they are:

```
!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~
```